# store user input in a string with IBAction

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a newbie in swift and I'm trying to store a user input of type string into a text field.
I initialized an empty string and then assigned it to the text field when the button is pressed but it keeps printing that the string is nil whenever I input data to the text field.

Here is the code I have so far

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var link: UITextField!
    var url = String()

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Hide the keyboard when the button is pressed
        self.link.resignFirstResponder()

        link.text = url
        print("The value of url is \(url)")
    }

    // Override function to hide the keyboard when the screen is touched
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep getting that error because the assignment you're doing is wrong. You just need to change

`link.text = url`

to

```
url = link.text
```

This is because in the assignment operation, the left operand is the destination of the value you want to assign, in this case "url", and the right operand is the source of the value you want to assign, in this case link.text.

As a general rule of thumb, remember this.

```
destinationVariable = sourceVariable
```

Answer (score 1):

> - ## Assignment Operator
>
>   The assignment operator (a = b) initializes or updates the value of a    with the value of b:
>
>   let b = 10
>
>   var a = 5
>
>   a = b       // a is now equal to 10

You need to change below mentioned line of code

```
 link.text = url
```

to

```
url = link.text!
```

Comment: @ Maddy `url = link.text!` This worked, thank you :)

Comment: That was a typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the reverse ways.

Change your code to

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Hide the keyboard when the button is pressed
    self.link.resignFirstResponder()

    url = link.text
    print("The value of url is \(url)")
}
```